# How can I set the default file type for a CFileDialog?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, file-type, cfiledialog

I am using `CFileDialog` for displaying the open file dialog. I have set the filter as follows:

```
static TCHAR BASED_CODE szFilter[] = _T("Chart Files (*.xlc)|*.xlc|")
                                     _T("Worksheet Files (*.xls)|*.xls|Data Files (*.xlc;*.xls)|")
                                     _T("*.xlc; *.xls|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");
```

I need to set the default file type to be "Worksheet Files" whenever I `DoModal` the dialog box. I am unable to figure out how to do it. MS Paint is doing, it selects the "All Picture files" when we open the open file dialog.

Please let me know how to do it.

Comment: Got the answer one can use nFilterIndex of OPENFILENAME to set the default selected file type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You're looking for the [`SetDefExt` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00e7zf6z.aspx).** This allows you to specify the default file extension for an open/save file dialog box. Remember that the string you specify should *not* contain a period (.).

Of course, you could also just specify this in the [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh5hz49d.aspx). The second parameter is the default extension (`lpszDefExt`).

Comment: Although MFC dialog have a somewhat twisted logic, changing default extension does not selects the default filter accordingly. Use nFilterIndex instead.

Comment: nFilterIndex is not a member of CFileDialog

Comment: @Michael `nFilterIndex` is a member of the `OPENFILENAME` structure, which, *I believe*, is exposed by `CFileDialog`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote https://stackoverflow.com/a/63054216/1592639 based on that ...

Answer (score 0):

You should read and write
This code will do the job during the run time of your program. To be able to display the last used selection next time you run your program, you can store the value of LastIndex in the Registry.

```
// A dialog box with several filters for various media file types
static int LastIndex = -1;          // Holds the last used filter. You can store it in the Registry to use it during next run.

const TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("Video Files (*.mpg, *.mov, *.mp4)|*.mpg;*.mov;*.mp4|Audio Files (*.wav, *.mp3, *.m4a, *.flac)|*.wav;*.mp3;*.m4a;*.flac|MXF Files (*.mxf)|*.mxf|All Files (*.*)|*.*||");

CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, _T("Select Media File"), NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST, szFilter, this);

if(LastIndex != -1) dlg.m_ofn.nFilterIndex = LastIndex; // restore last used index 
                                                        // from last time

if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    LastIndex = dlg.m_ofn.nFilterIndex; // Store last used index for next time
    CString sFilePath = dlg.GetPathName();
}
```